# Ignore cases while fetching the data from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fetching some data from a python dictionary and the key is `Number`. I want to ignore case sensitivity while looking up for the element. i.e. `NUMBER`

```
for row in dict_reader:
    part_number_list.append({row['Number'] + '.mod': row['Name']})
```

Is there a way to achieve the same in Python?

Comment: You'd have to use `upper()`, `lower()`, etc.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that automatically. You'll have to loop through the dictionary, checking if the key matches `number` case-insensitively.

Comment: Why don't you make the keys use a consistent case?

Comment: What if the dictionary has both `Number` and `NUMBER` keys?

Comment: @Barmar - it can never have both. Will only be one.

Comment: Is `dict_reader` from `csv.DictReader`?

Comment: Yeah, `dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)`

Answer (score 0):

You can search through [`dict_reader.fieldnames`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.fieldnames) to find the field name that matches case-insensitively. Then use that in the rest of the code.

```
for fn in dict_reader.fieldnames:
    if lower(fn) == 'number':
        num_field = fn
        break

for row in dict_reader:
    part_number_list.append({row[num_field] + '.mod': row['Name']})
```